# Maximum recommended socket sending capacity

Tags: c#, sockets, xna

I'm creating a program (it's a game) which will have multiplayer. It will need both client-to-server and server-to-client, with the server being run on one of the player's machines, not on a separate machine. I'll be using C# sockets, and I need to know the maximum amount of data that they can handle. For instance, my data will be between 256b and 128kb, I can assume. Am I going to have any trouble sending that through the sockets? (There will never be more than 7 clients connected to the server-handler machine).

**EDIT**

After reading some other posts, I don't think it will be a problem. Others have said that sending data upwards of 1MB doesn't cause a problem, so I don't think I'll have an issue.

P.S.

If this is not the case, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I would never recommend running the server of any serious game on the same machine as the client. It's just bound to result in terrible lagging for everyone.

Comment: You're right. There are plenty of related items that explain client server interations over a network socket. Essentially size isn't an issue if you stream.